# argparse optional parameter with optional/default values

Tags: python, argparse

In an application I need to have an optional parameter. And if that parameter is given the value has a default/optional setting.

IE the following cases:

```
python main.py  # value stored should be "None" (Or other indication optional parameter is not given
python main.py --ls  # value stored should be the default value ("testdir")
python main.py --ls=otherdir  # value stored should be 'otherdir'
```

However if the parser is setup like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Modify docker container definitions')
parser.add_argument('--ls', default='testdir', help="list")
```

it works quite differently:

```
python main.py  # value is 'testdir'
python main.py --ls  # error (missing argument)
python main.py --ls=otherdir  # value is 'otherdir'
```

How can I make argparse work like this? Or is there a logical reason such a setup cannot work?

Comment: As defined `--ls` expects one argument.  But if you make it 'optional', `nargs='?'` it will have the 3 way behavior  you want.  That use of '?' is inspired by `regex` notation.